# Using map and modulo to find product of digits in a number (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, product, modulo

Need to write a function that receives positive integer "numbers" and number of digits "n" and
returns the product of the digits in the number.
using modulo and map function and no loops.
this is what I have so far:

```
def digits(n):
    n = n % 10
def calc_digits(number, n):
        list1 = list(map(digits(number), number))
```

but I get 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this without a loop is to use recursion, which really is just looping in disguise:

```
def calc_digits( number ):
    if number:
        return number % 10 * calc_digits(number // 10)
    else:
        return 1

print( calc_digits( 12345) )
```

I did come up with a one-liner:

```
import functools
import operator
def calc_digits(digits):
    return functools.reduce(operator.mul, map(int,str(digits)))
```

Comment: is there no way to do this without recursion?

Comment: Sure, by using a loop.  Those are the two choices.  There is no magic here.  You have to iterate through the digits somehow.  Iteration is looping.  Did you see my second sample?  The only way you could use `map` is by converting the number to something that can be iterated, such as a string.

Comment: yes I understand, but I need to use map and modulo for the assignment and it seems using map like you suggested doesn't require using modulo (eg n % 10) so i'm just puzzled

Comment: It's a pointless trick question that doesn't teach you anything.  We've solved the problem two ways, one using modulo, one using map.  There's no way to use both without using a loop.  If you do get an answer, you might post it.